# Edit video using UIVideoEditorController

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uivideoeditorcontroller

I want to trim video so i am using UIVideoEditorController but when i check can edit file then it return false for all the files, mp4,mov,m4v. So any one will please guide me what is the problem.

1. Will you please give me the link of any tutorial of using UIVIdeoEditorcontroller

Answer (score 11):

UIVideoEditorController does not work on simulator so it always returns false, it will work fine on device.

Comment: spent all night just to find about this.

Answer (score 1):

You can find editing of video by path through `UIVideoEditorController`.

```
UIVideoEditorController* videoEditor = [[UIVideoEditorController alloc] init];
videoEditor.delegate=self;

NSString* videoPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"video" ofType:@"MOV"];
if ( [UIVideoEditorController canEditVideoAtPath:videoPath] )
{
    videoEditor.videoPath = videoPath;
    videoEditor.videoMaximumDuration = 10.0;

    //[self.customAvPlayerView addSubview:videoEditor.view];

    [self presentViewController:videoEditor animated:YES completion:nil];
} 
else
{
    NSLog( @"can't edit video at %@", videoPath );
}
```

http://www.raywenderlich.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=11571&p=60182